# perl extract numbers from string, edit, put back into string at their original position

Tags: string, perl

I'm trying to edit the numbers in a string and put it back in the same place as they have been before.

Example:

```
$string = "struct:{thin:[[75518103,75518217],[75518338,75518363],[75532810,75533910],],thick:[[75518363,75518424],[75521257,75521463],],}";
```

I need to edit the numbers, but want to keep the rest of the string at it is. Additionally the number of brackets can vary.

Until now I split the string at "," with
`@array = split (',',$string);`
and extracted the numbers for editing with

```
foreach (@array) { 
            $_ =~ s/\D//g;
            $_ = $number - $_;
}
```

now I want to put the numbers back in their original place in the string, but I don't know how.
Somehow I hope there is a better way to edit the numbers in the string without splitting it and extracting the numbers. Hope you can help me

Comment: Is this JSON, or another well-known format that has a parser around?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag by the way. Very good first post! :)

Comment: Then please go and smack whoever gave you that with a rolled up copy of the JSON spec. Because that's really irritating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression substitution [with the `/e` flag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace), search for long numbers and run Perl code in the substitution part.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $number = 100_000_000;
my $string = "struct:{thin:[[75518103,75518217],[75518338,75518363],[75532810,75533910],],thick:[[75518363,75518424],[75521257,75521463],],}";

$string =~ s/(\d+)/{$number - $1}/eg;

say $string;

__END__

struct:{thin:[[24481897,24481783],[24481662,24481637],[24467190,24466090],],thick:[[24481637,24481576],[24478743,24478537],],}
```

If there are no other numbers in the string, that would work. In case there is more logic involved, you can also move it into a subroutine and just call that in the substitution.

```
sub replace {
    return $_ % 2 ? $_ * 2 : $_ / 4;
}

$string =~ s/(\d+)/{replace($1)}/eg;
```

You might also need to revise the search pattern to be a bit more precise.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the evaluation modifier for regex! I now did it with

```
$string =~ s/([0-9]+)/$number-$1/eg;
```

and it worked!

Comment: I should not have wasted time looking for documentation. :P